# Changing Angular $location.path in response to a push service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently making an Angular/Ionic app which needs to change views in response to a push notification from [Google's Cloud Messaging Service](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Each view has it's on associated controller.

At the moment, my code is set up like the following: I have a push service, which receives the push notification, and broadcasts a message on the root scope to any interested controllers:

```
self.onNotificationGCM = function(data){
    switch(data.event){
        case "cancelled":
            $rootScope.$broadcast("orderCancellation", data.payload);
            break;
        case "completed":
            $rootScope.$broadcast("orderCompleted", data.payload);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

On a particular controller, the listener might look something like this:

```
$scope.$on("orderCompleted", function(event, data){
    $location.path('completedOrder');
    $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

The problem is that this code causes an error when the event is fired:

```
Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null
```

It seems as if the change of location within the listener is causing the current scope to be destroyed before the phase is complete. Is there a way to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Move the $apply to wrap the $broadcast. Usually it's better to $apply the broadcaster, as it saves you the need to $apply the handling method in all subscribers. In addition, it's better to wrap the applied code in $apply, as you have the benefit of angular's error handling.

```
self.onNotificationGCM = function(data){
    switch(data.event){
        case "cancelled":
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { // wrap in $apply
                $rootScope.$broadcast("orderCancellation", data.payload);
            });
            break;
        case "completed":
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { // wrap in $apply
                $rootScope.$broadcast("orderCompleted", data.payload);
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: OPs question was similar to mine but not exactly the same.  I was trying a location.path call in response to a desktop notification's onclick event.  Nevertheless your solution worked for me!  Thanks.